# How to predict on test set in matrix factorization collaborative filtering

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

Say I have df that looks like this

```
    userId     movieId    rating

0     1           31         1
1     1           34         5
2     1           742        2
3     1           1013       4
4     2           31         1
   ...
```

I've splitted using stratified sampling to keep same user in both train/test set.

When training on train dataset I would usually initialize embedding matrices for user and movies and try to learn using SGD.

After two matrices learned say P, Q. I take dot_product(P_i, Q.T_j) to get prediction for (i,j)th position in rating's matrix.

Since P,Q are learned embedding seems correct to use this learned embedding to predict validation dataset. However simply `validation_dataset - dot_product(P,Q)` doesn't make sense because shape of train and valid dataset are different.

One way to do is from original dataset take-out known ratings and keep it as validation set. However I am wondering if there is a way to split data first then apply learned embeddings to predict test set (this seems more intuitive to me however do not know how to do it...)

Answer (score 0):

The most widely accepted method to calculate test-set performance on collaborative-filtering systems is to keep some number of *known* user-item interactions separate, in the form of a test set. We exclude those test-set interactions from the training set, which is used to train the model.

After training, for each pair of user *u* and item *i* in the test set, we compute the model's predicted interaction score for *u* and *i*, and compare it with the known interaction score, which is either 1 or 0 (0 when negative-sampling is used). This is how we compute the test-set performance metrics.

If you use the model's predicted ratings/scores to *create* new data-points for the test-set, then it may not reflect the true generalization performance of the model on completely unseen/new data. Let me know if that answers your question, or if any clarifications are needed.